# set value to nested state using variable in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, state

I have defined a variable which will paste value as key inside userInfo.

```
this.state = {
      userInfo: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: ""
      }
}
//_________________________________________
onChange = (e)=>{
    var stateChild = e.target.name // stateChild here is variable which will return (firstname, lastName or email) of userInfo
    var userInfo = {
     // ...this.state.userInfo
    }
    userInfo.stateChild = e.target.value; //  I want to paste state child's value here
    console.log(userInfo.stateChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't any `setState` in your handler. Have you tried:

```
this.state = {
  userInfo: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: ""
  }
};

onChange = e => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    userInfo: {
      ...prevState.userInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
  }));
};
```

Comment: using this it created new key inside userInfo. i expect to modify the value of the key that match to e.target.name

Comment: what is the new key created?

Comment: i mean  if e.target .name = firstName, it did't pass value to the firstName. it seem create new firstName.

Comment: No, it can't be two the same keys in object :)